# Finding all solutions to $\cos \theta = −\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ in a given interval

Tags: trigonometry

> Find all solutions between $-2\pi$ and $2\pi$ of the following equation:
>   $$\cos \theta = −\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
>   Give all answers in radians.

Now I have drawn the graph between $−2\pi$ and $2\pi$. 
Am I correct thinking that $\cos \theta = 2\pi - \theta$?

I am completely at a loss of where to draw the values on the graph to work this out.

Comment: You should have $\cos\theta = \color{red}{\cos}(2\pi - \theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking that $\cos{\theta} = 2\pi - \theta$ is wrong. Take the example $\theta = 0$ and we have $\cos{0} = 1 \neq 2\pi$.

We have that $\theta = \cos^{-1} \left (-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right )+2\pi k$ or $\theta = -\cos^{-1} \left(-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)+2\pi k$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Thus, $\theta = \dfrac{3 \pi}{4}+2\pi k$ or $\theta = -\dfrac{3 \pi}{4}+2\pi k$.

In the range $-2 \pi$ to $2 \pi$, our solutions are $\dfrac{3 \pi}{4}$, $-\dfrac{3 \pi}{4}$, $\dfrac{5 \pi}{4}$, and $-\dfrac{5 \pi}{4}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and clarification

Comment: I guess that $\cos \theta=2\pi-\theta$ in the OPs question is a typo and should read $\cos\theta=\color{green}\cos(2\pi-\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry, $\cos\theta = \cos(-\theta)$.

[image: symmetry_for_sine_and_cosine]

Moreover, since two coterminal angles have the same cosine, 
\begin{align*}
\cos(\theta + 2n\pi) & = \cos\theta, n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
\cos(-\theta + 2n\pi) & = \cos(-\theta) = \cos\theta, n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of integers.

One solution for the equation 
$$\cos\theta = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
is 
$$\theta = \arccos\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = \frac{3\pi}{4}$$
Hence, the general solution is 
\begin{align*}
\theta & = \frac{3\pi}{4} + 2m\pi, m \in \mathbb{Z} & \theta = -\frac{3\pi}{4} + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*} 
The requirement that $-2\pi \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ implies that $m = 0, -1$ and that $n = 0, 1$, which yields the solutions 
$$\theta = \pm \frac{3\pi}{4}, \pm \frac{5\pi}{4}$$